# how to handle 2 checkboxes to hide or show certain divs React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have this code

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked
    })
  }

  render() {
    const hidden_chk1 = this.state.checked ? 'hidden' : '';
    const hidden_chk2 = this.state.checked ? 'hidden' : '';

    return <div>
        <div>
        <label>Check 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1"className="chk11" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <label>Check 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" className="chk22" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
      </div>

      <div className={ hidden_chk1 }>show hide div with check 1</div>
      <div className={ hidden_chk2 }>show hide div with check 2</div>

    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

here's the JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v5xsawn8/1/

I'm struggling with this and can't make it work, the checkbox 1 have to control the div check 1 hidden_chk1 only and the checkbox 2 have to control the div checkbox2 hidden_chk2 only, they have to be independent, thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is you are trying use the same state to control 2 checkboxes. You would need 2 different states for each checkbox independently to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working here is the code:

JS

```
class Componente extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { checked: false, checked2: false};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);

  }  

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked      
    })
  }

  handleChange2() {
    this.setState({
        checked2: !this.state.checked2      
    })
  }

  render() {
    const togglecheck1 = this.state.checked ? 'hidden-check1' : '';
    const togglecheck2 = this.state.checked2 ? 'hidden-check2' : '';

    return <div>
        <div>
        <label>Check 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1"className="chk11" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <label>Check 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" className="chk22" checked={ this.state.checked2 } onChange={ this.handleChange2 } />
      </div>

      <div className={ togglecheck1 }>show hide div with check 1</div>
      <div className={ togglecheck2 }>show hide div with check 2</div>

    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Componente />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

CSS

```
.hidden-check1 {  
  display: none;
}

.hidden-check2{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

html

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

in css =>visibility: hidden hide the div and keep the space and =>
display: none hide the div and dont keep space.
here's the codepen http://codepen.io/parlop/pen/EKmaWM
, thanks.